# Bibliography section has the wrong header

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer

I'm writing a thesis document. After the Appendix section I have the Reference section.

My problem is that my References have three pages total, in the first page appears the bibliography title correctly, as the next picture shows:

[image]

But in the next two pages the header appears as if it were part of the appendix, like this:

[image]

NOTE: This has the same result if I place the bibliography before the appendix, except that in this case the header changes to the one of the last chapter.

**EDIT:** This is the code where I call the chapters, appendix and bibliography. Hope it helps to find a solution:

```
\documentclass[oneside,numbers,a4paper,spanish]{ezthesis}

\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}

\author{**}
\title{**}
\degree{**}
\supervisor{**}
\institution{**}
\faculty{**}
\department{**}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill--\ \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}
\makeatother


\hyperlinking
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla} 

\include{Chapters/titlepage}

\include{Chapters/gracias}

\tableofcontents

%% # Chapters#
\include{Chapters/1}
\include{Chapters/2}
\include{Chapters/3}
\include{Chapters/4}
\include{Chapters/5}
\include{Chapters/6}

\appendix
\include{appendix/apendiceA}
\include{appendix/apendiceB}
\include{appendix/apendiceC}
\include{appendix/apendiceD}

\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2:** This link have the ezthesis: [EZTHESIS](http://navarroj.com/latex/ezthesis.html)

How could I fix this?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the document class used (`ezthesis`)?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I update the post with the link to ezthesis

Comment: as a last resort, you could put `\clearpage` and `\markboth{Bibliografia}{Bibliografia}` before `\bibliography{biblio}` to reset the running heads.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @barbarabeeton 's comment I could fix my problem. Maybe it wasn't the best way to solve it, but it works.

This is the code to solve the problem:

"put `\clearpage` and `\markboth{Bibliografia}{Bibliografia}` before `\bibliography{biblio}` to reset the running heads". – barbara beeton

Thanks for the help

Comment: I think this *is* the best way to solve this, and it is pretty much what the standard `book` class does: `\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}`. You probably should also ask the author of `ezthesis` to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The appendices (non-essential stuff, that just might interest the reader; but probably won't) go *after* the bibliography. This is an old custom in printing, which you shouldn't challenge without solid reasons.